# Obtain Grails plugin version at runtime

Tags: grails, plugins, runtime, version

Is it possible to obtain version of a specific Grails plugin at runtime, let say in Bootstrap class? Or more generically, how to query loaded plugins from the parent Grails applications and obtain their names and version numbers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest way is to interact with the `pluginManager` bean.

```
class BootStrap {

    def pluginManager

    def init = { servletContext ->
        // retrieve them all...
        pluginManager.allPlugins.each { plugin ->
            println "Plugin: ${plugin.name}, Version: ${plugin.version}"
        }

        // retrieve a specific plugin...
        def hibPlugin = pluginManager.getGrailsPlugin('hibernate4')
        println "Hibernate Plugin Version: ${hibPlugin.version}"
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you know if there is anyway to get similar info for jars?

Comment: @MoreThanFive There might be for specific jars but there is no general solution to answer a question like "what version is this jar?" because jars are not all versioned and the ones that are versioned are not 100% versioned in a uniformed way.  If you are only concerned with jars that are related to dependencies of your Grails build, there are ways to discover those along with metadata including version numbers.  The `grails dependency-report` command takes advantage of that metadata and may serve as a good example starting point.