# Versions of plugins + jars at runtime Grails

Tags: grails

Is it possible to find out what versions of the various plugins that are in my war / class loader at runtime?  The reason I want to do this so that I can be 100% sure at runtime what version of what is in production.

I see a mechanism in this thread: [Obtain Grails plugin version at runtime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24665629/obtain-grails-plugin-version-at-runtime)

But was wondering how I would get this in a GSP? Also, this does not give me the jar versions. Thanks

Comment: Don't put code in GSPs, this isn't PHP. Render the response and go. Instead, pass that data down from the controller (which should probably hand off the work to a service, because this isn't in any way related to controller logic, routing, databinding, etc.)

Answer (score 0):

Can't get it for jars but to display in GSP, do...
controller:

```
class MetaController {

    def pluginManager
    def plugins

    def index() {
        log.debug(">>index()")
        // retrieve them all...
        plugins = pluginManager.allPlugins.collect { plugin ->
            log.debug("Plugin: ${plugin.name}, Version: ${plugin.version}")
            return "Plugin: ${plugin.name}, Version: ${plugin.version}"
        }

        plugins.sort()
        [plugins: plugins]
    }
}
```

View...

```
 ...
<g:each in="${plugins}" var="p">
    <li>${p}</li>
</g:each>
```